# js plugin from different source not working

Tags: jquery

I am using this jquery's,can plugin from this different source work? if i include both the plugin then one of them is not working,how can i make both of them work

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"  src="dropdown-check-list.1.9/js/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src= "dropdown-check-list.1.9/src/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src= "dropdown-check-list.1.9/src/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="dropdown-check-list.1.9/src/ui.dropdownchecklist.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the different jQuery distro's to different global variables. Only one can house in the `$` variable.

```
<script src="dropdown-check-list.1.9/src/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq161 = window.jQuery;
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var $ = window.jQuery; // Not needed per se
</script>
```

An alternative is to use this; http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .noConflict().Because some conflict is exist here